# How can i fetch the datarow value where i can see that who has?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

The Highlighted part i want that name to be fetch and display on another.

[image: The Highlighted part i want that name to be fetch and display on another.]

This is code that on click the entry of data is done and please say  where 1 is return that place what value will come and 2 no where i want to say that with name successful login and 3 is where the name will direct with page
. So Please help me out from this thanks in advance to the replier and may this will be helpful for new one to code.

[image: This is code that on click the entry of data is done and please say where 1 is return that place what value will come and 2 no where i want to say that with name successful login and 3 is where the name will direct with page . So Please help me out from this thanks in advance to the replier and may this will be helpful for new one to code.]

Comment: In general, you should paste your code into your question.  Links/Images are not good resources for your code samples, as the URL could become unavailable in the future and therefore if someone tries to reference this post it would be partly useless. You should read this first and then try asking/editing your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's really hard to see what the code is from your screen shot. I recommend you post the code in your question.

Comment: Sorry for that i'll add code in next question